# can i access a directory list on mobile devices using Trigger.io?

Tags: trigger.io

I want access to the file system to get a list of the photos on the device so as to be able to display them in my app.

I don't see a method in the API providing that information. Is there a way of getting at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have an API method to list all the photos taken via your app, but you do have options for how to do that yourself.

Firstly, when doing `forge.file.getImage`, you can save the file objects for later use - in `forge.prefs`, for example, which does have a [list keys method](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/prefs.html#prefs.keys).

Or, if the photos are saved to the gallery, you could use the `source: "gallery"` argument to getImage, which would let the user browser through the available photos and select one.

Comment: thanks, yes, i think i'll have to do the second option there. What i'm really after though is getting at photos on the device without user interaction. - would like to create a replacement for photo gallery.